# Routing Issue in Laravel - Not found error

Tags: php, laravel, caching, routes

When I am trying to access my project I get:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found

I have investigated the issue and found that running: `php artisan route:list` is returning empty even though my routes/web.php has a lot of routes:

```
/** Auth Routes*/
Auth::routes();

/** Homepage Route*/
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('layout');
});
```

I have tried all kind of commands:

```
php artisan route:cache
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: What route are you trying to access?

Comment: I tried to access all routes, i just posted a few of them in the post. None is working

Comment: Yes I have the view created.

Comment: is auth routes working?